# How to run binary like `pdflatex` on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, latex, pdflatex

Since AWS Lambda supports [running binaries](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/), I wanted to run `pdflatex` in AWS Lambda, but I stumbled upon a few problems. I have successfully ran other binaries, but `pdflatex` has many shared OS libraries dependencies and I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

The sample code looks like this:

```
'use strict';
let exec = require('child_process').exec;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const child = exec('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin/ ./pdflatex my-file.tex', (error) => {
    callback(error, 'Process complete!');
  });
  child.stdout.on('data', console.log);
  child.stderr.on('data', console.error);
};
```

And the ZIP file looks like this:

```
index.js -------------- where the above code is
pdflatex -------------- binary from my OS
my-file.tex ----------- a sample LaTeX document
bin/ ------------------ folder with shared OS libraries
```

The uploaded ZIP file contains all of the above.

I generated the `pdflatex` with `cp $(which pdflatex) pdflatex`.

1. Is this the right way to upload the `pdflatex` it? Is there any problem with this method? Is there a better way?

After trying to run for the first time, AWS Lambda complained that many `lib_____.so` were missing, so I copied them from my machine to the `bin/` folder inside of the ZIP. I used `ldd $(which pdflatex)` to look for `pdflatex`'s dependencies.

However, as I imagined, they were incompatible with the Linux version that runs AWS Lambda, so I fired a CentOS and copied the `lib______.so` files to the `bin/` folder, but this didn't work either.

2. Is there a way to "dump" a self-contained version of `pdflatex` that contained all the required dependencies and would run with no need of shared OS libraries?
3. Do I need to compile `pdflatex` inside an Amazon Linux instance? What if I compiled it in a 64 bit architecture and the code ran on a 32 bit architecture, wouldn't it fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to generate binaries for use in a Lambda is to either copy or compile them on the same version of Linux that Lambda uses.  Amazon has a list of AMI images here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html.  Create an EC2 instance from one of those, install the packages, and copy the files into your zip as you've done.

For #2, you can simplify the dependencies by doing a static compile, but I wouldn't try that unless you're familiar with building packages from source.  You'll need to compile with `-static` at the link stage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on AMI. Can you point me to the direction on how compile LeTeX using `-static` flag?